# Removing only the number from every item in a python list (whilst keeping the words)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list in python in which every string also has a number as part of it, I.e:

```
list = ['Hello 12', 'Things 54', 'Twice 23']
```

I need it to become a list which retains all the original strings but without any of the number, I.e:

```
list = ['Hello', 'Things', 'Twice']
```

Is there a simple way to iterate through the list and remove only the numbers from each item in the list?

Comment: Is the number always last? Your sample output also has the space before the number removed, is that an additional requirement? What about other spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub). Here, `\s*` is 0 or more whitespace characters, `\d+` is 1 or more digits.

```
import re
lst = ['Hello 12', 'Things 54', 'Twice 23']
lst = [re.sub(r'\s*\d+', '', s) for s in lst]
print(lst)
# ['Hello', 'Things', 'Twice']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) along with [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> items = ['Hello 12', 'Things 54', 'Twice 23']
>>> items_sans_nums = [''.join(c for c in item if c.isalpha()) for item in items]
>>> items_sans_nums
['Hello', 'Things', 'Twice']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regexp replacement to remove all the digits.

```
import re

new_list = [re.sub(r'\d', '', s) for s in old_list]
```